# c/c++ stock bitmap using hexadecimal letters and convert back

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, hex

I have a bitmap stocked as a unsigned char array, containing only 1 and 0; like this:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

I wish to stock this in a compact way, so I wrote a function to convert this into hexadecimals. I'll stock this like:

```
0f33
```

My question now: with which function can I convert these characters back into my bitmap? when I have a pointer to the character "f", how can I convert that into the integer value 15? (I know a switch case would do the trick, but probably there is a better way?)

Comment: check out these functions for printing binary from variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format

Comment: Would you prefer the answer to be in `C` or `C++`?

Comment: possibly typo: f into 16 ...did you mean 15?

Comment: if you (s)print it isn't (s)scanf your friend then?

Comment: Design considerations -- Depending on your requirements, maybe std::bitset <T> is what you should use instead of char arrays and conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for C++:

```
int number;
std::stringsteam ss;
ss << std::hex << *characterPointer;
ss >> number;
```

For C:

```
char hexstr[2] = {*characterPointer, '\0'};
int number = (int)strtol(hexstr, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: strtoll will read the whole string into one long number. I just want it to read one char at a time and convert it to the corresponding int...

Comment: my matrix is quite big so I'll get overflow if i try to read it all at once... and I'll still need to convert back to my char array...

Comment: @ChrisMaes Yes, you see the first line? It turns the single character into character string with only it and `\0`.

Comment: ok I'm sorry, missed that... works fine allright.. was only hoping there would be a better/ more efficient way to do this conversion back and forth....

Comment: Why not decoding whole bytes? `char hexstr[3] = {*(c+1), *c, 0 };`